# I want to move sprite body when touch point detect

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I want to move sprite body when i touch screen but it cant happen...

```
-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for(b2Body *b=world->GetBodyList();b;b=b->GetNext())
    {
    CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
        location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
         b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);


        if(b->GetUserData()!=NULL)
        {
        CCSprite *sprite =(CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();

            b->SetTransform(b2Vec2(location.x, location.y), 0);
            id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4 position:CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO)];
             [sprite runAction:action];
        }
     }
}
```

please help me...
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code it would work for you.

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{       
    for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
        for(b2Body *b=world->GetBodyList();b;b=b->GetNext())
        {
            if(b->GetUserData()!=NULL)
            {
                CCSprite *sprite =(CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
                b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
                b->SetTransform(b2Vec2(locationWorld.x, locationWorld.y), 0);
                id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4 position:CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO)];
                [sprite runAction:action];

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The sprite with the body moves to a location where the touch is Ended.

Answer (score 0):

add `self.isTouchEnabled = YES;` in your init method